# Difference between Worksheets & Worksheet obj

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to understand the difference between `worksheets` & `worksheet` obj in Excel VBA. I understand from the MSDN reference that the `worksheet` is a child obj of `worksheets` & `sheets`.

However, we reference every worksheet using the `worksheets` obj, not the `worksheet` obj. e.g.

```
worksheets("ExcelIsCool").range("a1").value -> CORRECT
worksheet ("ExcelIsCool").range("a1").value -> INCORRECT
```

My question is whats the difference between the two?

Is `worksheet` only used for declaring a variable (the only place where I've used so far). e.g.

```
dim wks as worksheet
```

Comment: Yes, Worksheet is only used for declaring a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Worksheets is a collection of Worksheet objects. A "Workbook" has one or more "Worksheets" - the collection, whilst a specific object from the collection is a "Worksheet".

In your example, you are trying to select a worksheet from the collection by name, but since one worksheet by itself isn't a worksheet collection, it will not work. When you do ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheetName") the returned value is a worksheet object, so you can interact with it in the way described.

Edit: Use Cases

Well, use `Worksheet` when you want it to be clear you are working with a worksheet, when you want to keep your functions clean of multiple responsibilities, and where you want good intellisense support inspecting the `Worksheet`'s members. So if you are taking a worksheet as a parameter to some function (for example, a function that finds that last row of data from the bottom in a given column), your function signature could look like this:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByRef wsTarget as Excel.Worksheet, ByVal column as Long) as Long
    GetLastRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

This is nice, because it means you are passing around the actual object you want to refer to, rather than a string or number) (its name or index). It also means the called function (GetLastRow) doesn't need to know about which workbook the sheet is in (`ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` are not always the same). This gives the caller the responsibility to locate the sheet and make sure you get the right one, keeping the function clean. A user could call it with a worksheet's variable name (as displayed in one of the VBA editor panels):

`last_row = GetLastRow(Sheet1, 1)`

Or any of the other ways of referencing worksheets (see [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/)).

You use the Worksheet object anytime you want to talk about only one sheet. Explicitly declaring your variable as a Worksheet object will give you the intellisense options appropriate to working with a worksheet. And it's clear to a reader that you are working with a worksheet, not a string.

Comment: Thank you for adding to this! Good explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Like @Orphid has already stated, `Worksheets` is a [`collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.90).aspx) of `Worksheet` objects.

When declaring a `Worksheet` variable, you can explicitly declare it as such.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

So you're declaring a `Worksheet` from the `Collection` of `Worksheets`.

You can also loop through each `Worksheet` within a `Collection`.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws
```

So you can see that `Worksheet` is used in scenarios where you're explicitly referring to a single `Worksheet`, primarily when declaring a variable.

Comment: +One, Worksheet is an entity just for management of all sheets (Worksheets)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is purely syntactical in your case, but it is important to distinguish between the actual object and the programmatic "object". For instance, you can use both of these:

Worksheet Collection:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "1"`

Worksheet "Object":

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")
wks.Range("A1").Value = "1"
```

There is no meaningful difference, except ease of use and sometimes better readability -- they both reference the actual object, which is "Sheet1". In Excel terminology, wks is also often referred to as an object, but what's important for you to remember is that wks *represents* an object, it isn't an object in itself.

Everything you can do with wks, you can also do with Worksheets("Sheet1") -- it's just two not-so-different ways of referring to the worksheet in question. In fact, in this particular example, "object" (like wks) is practically equivalent with "alias".

Comment: I donot believe the statement 'There is no meaningful difference...' is true.

Comment: For the simple use-case OP provides, I would be happy to be proven wrong. What can you do with wks that you cannot do by writing out the Collection reference?