# Some doubts about Dim and Set Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Normally, Dim should be done first and then Set should be done in vba code, like the below code.

```
Dim xWs1 As Worksheet
Dim xWs2 As Worksheet
.
.
.
Dim xWsN As Worksheet
Set xWs1 = Worksheets("A")
Set xWs2 = Worksheets("B")
.
.
.
Set xWsN = Worksheets("NNN")
```

If I need to Dim and Set 5 worksheets, 10 lines of code will be needed. It seems that the code will be too long when I need to Dim and Set more than 5 worksheets.

I found that if I just use Set, the vba code can also run properly. I would like to ask this will cause any problems if I didn't use Dim?

```
Set xWs1 = Worksheets("A")
Set xWs2 = Worksheets("B")
.
.
.
Set xWsN = Worksheets("NNN")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are _implicitly_ declaring your variables. It doesn't break your code, but can be a debugging nightmare if you misspell a variable or try to use a wrong data type then you expect it to take.

Comment: Your code works without `Dim` because you have no `Option Explicit` . This is not good practice as it prevents your typos from being detected.

Comment: And though it is generally considered bad practice and makes debugging harder, you can do multiple declarations on the same line Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet.

Comment: @Drager Do I have an answer for you!  .....give me a couple minutes to explain

Comment: Thanks all, you solved my doubts. @QHarr thanks your advice, I will try it in my code.

Comment: At your own peril. I don't have multiple declarations on the same line unless I am being super lazy and even then no more than a couple of objects!

Comment: @QHarr I found that can also do it like this Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet. Is it not more readable? Why do you not recommend to do so?

Comment: It is implicitly declaring all but the last as variants. Only the last is a Worksheet object. Not putting the type in the Dim = implicit variant.

Comment: I See. Thanks, you clarify me one more concept of vba.

Comment: @Drager you already have an answer. However, you've not explained the actions to be performed on each sheet. If actions to be performed are the same then some other alternative can also be suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following example of why using implicit variable declaration is *usually* a bad idea:

```
Sub Test()

    myVariable = 10

    myOutcome = myVaraible + 5

End Test
```

`myOutcome` = 5. Can you see why?

I misspelled `myVariable` in the second line, so I just essentially created a brand new variable `myVaraible` (which had a default value of 0).

This is why you should always use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every module; and why you should always explicitly declare all variables.

While it still works, you are just setting yourself up for needless debugging headaches.

---

If your issue is that you want to condense your code to use less lines, you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myVariable As Long:    myVariable = 10
    Dim myOutput As Long
    myOutput = myVariable + 5

End Sub
```

---

You can also declare multiple variables on the same line:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myVariable As Long, myOutput As Long
    myVariable = 10
    myOutput = myVariable + 5

End Sub
```

---

Not necessarily recommending this (as it can degrade readability), but it's yet another method of declaring variables. This does require the same data type, but you can add your worksheets in an array (from your example):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim xWs(1 To 5) As Worksheet

    Set xWs(1) = Worksheets("A")
    Set xWs(2) = Worksheets("B")
    Set xWs(3) = Worksheets("C")
    Set xWs(4) = Worksheets("D")
    Set xWs(5) = Worksheets("E")

End Sub
```

Comment: This I know, but if I just use Set e.g. Set xWs = Worksheets("A"), Set xWs2 = Worksheets("B") xWs.cells(1,1).value = xWs2.cells(1,1).value. There are no error happened, and the code run properly. So I have a doubt that Set worksheets can be not using Dim?

Comment: @Drager That's what I am saying. You do _not have to_ use `Dim` (declare your variables). But in doing so, you are running the risk of typos. That's the entire reason `Dim` exists, just to prevent from accidentally using `xWss1` instead of `xWs1`, because Excel will notify you that you didn't declare a variable when using `Option Explicit`. It also prevents you from trying to use a wrong data type then what you declared.

Comment: In a nutshell, `Dim` is there as a "safety feature", not as a requirement.

Comment: Oh thanks. Originally, I would like to just use Set to shorten the code lines. After reading your comment, just using Set cannot run when using Option Explicit. It seems that using Dim is safer for preventing error.

Comment: Dim is also there to ensure you declare a tyoe so that the correct memory allocation is given for the object to be worked with.

Comment: @QHarr Very good point. Not too much of an issue for small projects, but memory allocation is very important in general programming.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use dim statement , variable is automatically created as a Variant type.

The Variant type can be an integer, a string, a workbook, or any of the other type of variable and it can change as the variable changes, one moment it can be a string, then it can be changed to a workbook.

Using Dim

[image]

Without using Dim

[image]

There are mainly two problems with not using Dim,

1. Variant types uses more computer memory as a result it will make your code slow especially when you use loops.
2. Difficult to find errors ( in your case you can assign anything to variable XWs1 such as numbers , names etc. which can be avoided if you use dim)

Comment: Thanks. I ignored the memory problems, you clarify me some basic concept of vba. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## How to Declare and Set 92 Objects using 92 Characters:

If "taking up space" is your concern, and you hypothetically want to explicitly set **5** procedure-level variables (`w1..w5`) to **`Set`** to **5** worksheets (`Sht1..Sht5`), you could use:

**Example #1:**

```
DefObj W
Sub wSet1()
  Dim w1, w2, w3, w4, w5
  Set w1=[Sht1]:Set w2=[Sht2]:Set w3=[Sht3]:Set w4=[Sht4]:Set w5=[Sht5]
End Sub
```

---

...or, even more space-efficient, if for example, you had **92** worksheets to `Set` in ***92 declared variables***? Then:

**Example #2:**

```
DefObj W
Sub wSet2():Dim wks(1To 92),x:For x=1To 92:Set wks(x)=Sheets("Sht"&x):Next x:End Sub
```

<sub>(That's 92 characters... not counting the line feed!)</sub>

---

## Explanation:

Between these two ways of shortening declaration, we're using six shortcuts.  Below is a summary of each, and see the links under "More Information" for full documentation on each.

> **Disclaimer:** There are a number of reasons we shouldn't use shortcuts in programming.  The obvious one is that, the more you compress code, the harder it is to read and understand (especially by others), and therefore can be harder to troubleshoot or expand upon.
>
> <sub>If you don't know what the "standard methods" are, do not learn the shortcuts first!  Learn how to do things "THE RIGHT WAY" before learning the shortcuts, no matter how appealing it may seem.  There was a time that I argued that neatness like indentation and commenting, and *full*, proper techniques, didn't matter.  I was wrong; had to learn that the hard way.  If you're reading this, you'll probably have to learn the hard way too, **but at least:**</sub>
>
> <sub>**Don't use shortcuts when posting** example code in your Stack Overflow questions.  (This is *not* a method of  [[MCVE]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!)  **You will probably get yelled at!** ...and possibly have you questions down-voted or ignored...  ***You were warned!***</sub>

---

## ✓ `DefObj` <sub><sup>(Default Data Types)</sup></sub>

```
[Deftype statements][1] are a forgotten method of declaring default data types.  Normally, the default data type is [`Variant`][2], so this:

Dim myVariable as Variant
```

...is identical to:

```
Dim myVariable
```

...however the `DefObj W` statement (used at module-level) says:

> All variables declared in this module, ***that start with the letter* 'W'** default to type `Object` (unless otherwise specified).  Note that *Deftypes* statements must be used at module-level (before your first `Sub`).
>
> The entire list:  ([More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263422(v=vs.60).aspx))
>
> `DefBool DefByte DefCur DefDate DefDbl DefDec DefInt DefLng DefSng DefStr DefObj DefVar`

---

## ✓ `,` <sub><sup>(Commas in 'Dim' Statements)</sup></sub>

When declaring variables with `Dim`, multiple variables can be listed on the same line, separated with a comma.  Therefore this:

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim myVariable1 as Currency  
    Dim myVariable2 as Currency  
    …
```

...is identical to this: (combining examples with *Deftypes*)

```
DefCur m
Sub mySub()
    Dim myVariable1, myVariable1 
    …
```

---

## ✓ `Sheets` <sub><sup>('Sheets' collection)</sup></sub>

- The **`WorkSheets` Object** refers to the collection of **all the *Worksheet* objects** in the specified or active workbook.
- The **`Charts` Object` refers to the collection of **all the *Chart* objects** in the specified or active workbook.

  - But the **`Sheets` Object`refers to ***both*** the`Worksheets`*and*`Charts` collections.

So, if a workbook has **3 worksheets and 2 chart sheet**, in VBA:

- `Sheets.Count` will return `5`
- `Worksheets.Count` will return `3`

> **Warning:** Using `Sheets` could cause a conflict if you have a Chart and a Worksheet with the same name (and should also be avoided when referring to worksheets in other files).  But for a simple single-file, worksheet-only workbook, save yourself some *`Work`* and stick with just **`Sheets`**.

---

## ✓ `[ ]` <sub><sup>(Square-Bracket Reference Shortcuts)</sup></sub>

[Square brackets] can be used as a shortcut when referring to **Worksheets**, **Cell Ranges** ***and*** individual **Cells**.  You can use either the *`A1` Reference Style* or a **named range** within brackets as a shortcut for the Range property. You do not have to type the word "Range" or use quotation marks.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1:B5].ClearContents 

[MyRange].Value = 30
```

This is barely [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation), and even less documented is the fact that, if used in the logical order, square brackets can be used to refer to worksheets.

Combining examples, **all of these statements will have identical result**:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Now()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Now()
Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1] = Now()
Sheets("Sheet1").[A1] = Now()
[Sheet1].[A1] = Now()
```

---

## ✓ `wks()` <sub><sup>(Variable Arrays)</sup></sub>

If you have a large number of similar objects to declare, it's often easier (and more organized) to group them together in an array.  An array can be declared as any type including, for example, Object, Worksheet. <sub>(...or even the rarely-used and bizarre types like [LongLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/longlong-data-type) and [IConverterApplicationPreferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/iconverterapplicationpreferences-hrgetlcid-method-office). (Apparently whoever thought up that one doesn't care for shortcuts.)</sub>

---

## ✓ `For..Set..Next` <sub><sup>(Loop to Set Variable Arrays)</sup></sub>

When using an array of objects (any any variable sets), the next logical step is to reduce code with any tasks that need to be performed on the entire group of objects.

---

### Other Notes:

Example #1 could have been compressed to one line but I wanted it to be easy to read in the answer.  If our sheet names were **`S1..S5`** instead of *the oh-so-lengthy* `Sht1..Sht5`, *and* we use the `:`, we could accomplish the same thing in 105 characters:

**Example #1b:**

```
DefObj W
Sub wSet():Dim w1,w2,w3,w4,w5:Set w1=[S1]:Set w2=[S2]:Set w3=[S3]:Set w4=[S4]:Set w5=[S5]:End Sub
```

---

### Data Type Shortcut Symbols

Another rarely used set of dates back to 1974: data type shortcuts chosen by [Gary Kildall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall) for the CP/M Operating System

**`Symbol  Data Type  Constant`**

```
%       Integer    vbInteger = 2
$       String     vbString = 8
&       Long       vbLong = 3
@       Decimal    vbDecimal = 6
!       Single     vbSingle = 4
#       Double     vbDouble = 5
```

Still supported today in many coding languages, you could for example use these interchangeably:

```
Dim myVariable as String
Dim myVariable$
```

---

## More Information:

- Microsoft.com : [**How to Break and Combine Statements in Code**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code) (VB/VBA)
- MSDN : [**Refer to Cells by Using Shortcut Notation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation)
- Excel Hero : [**Excel VBA Shortcut Range References**](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html)
- MSDN : [**Using Data Types Efficiently**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/using-data-types-efficiently)
- MSDN : [**Dim Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352(v=vs.60).aspx) (VBA)
- ExcelHowTo : [**`Worksheets` vs. `Sheets`**](http://www.excelhowto.com/worksheets-vs-sheets/)
- Stack Overflow : [**Difference between `Worksheets` & `Worksheet` objects**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32370081/8112776)
- MSDN : [**`Set` Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement)
- MSDN : [**Declaring Arrays**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-arrays)

Comment: Oh, a really detailed explanation. Thanks a lot. I just have a question that you use Dim ... As Variant in your code. Is it not using Dim ... As Worksheet better for memory allocation? Besides, thank you teaching me DefObj that I have not learnt. The other things that I think I know what you said such as [Sht1] (Evaluate), wks() (Array), For..Set..Next (For loop) and Sheets (Object).

Comment: @ashleedawg, you wrote _”if you have a Chart and a Worksheet with the same name”_. But is it really possible? I’m not by any PC to test it now, but I seem to recall it wasn’t possible.